# Issues using a variable to get a image in batch

Tags: batch-file, random, file-exists

I was trying to make a batch file that would create a random number between 1 and 13 and get the file called "[random number].jpg", but it isn't working.

The code:

```
SET /A rand=%RANDOM% * 13 / 32768 + 1
IF NOT EXIST "IMGS\%rand%.jpg" (
    ECHO ERR: File " %rand%.jpg " not found
    pause
    EXIT
)
```

The output:
    `ERR: File " 6.jpg " not found`

Any thoughts on why it's doing this?

Comment: You are positive that is the correct relative path to the file?

Comment: Yes, I've double-checked that.

Comment: Well to be absolutely certain, I would advise you put an `ECHO %CD%` in your code to be absolutely sure.

Comment: @Squashman It says that it's in system32, which I now realize is because it needs to be started in administrator mode. Is there any way I can go to the batch file's path without putting in the entire path? I have plans for it to be portable to different pcs.

Comment: The batch file is used with the %0 argument.  If you want just the path then use the command modifiers. `%~dp0`

Comment: You could also shorten your rand assignment to this: `SET /A rand=%RANDOM% %% 13 + 1`

Comment: using `cd %~dp0`, it now works there, though now my issue has nothing to do with that, but the registry and what I was using the random file choosing for. It modifies the registry key to the correct thing, but I have to copy it from the registry key into something else and then back to it for it to work. I'm trying to change the wallpaper with its registry key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. Do you know why it's doing this and a workaround or should I ask it in a different question?